# Why won't admob interstitial ads display?

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, ads

So I've added banner and interstitial ads both from admob in my unity android project.So I've tested it on my test device and my banner ad is showing fine but my interstitial ad won't display.

I've made it on every 11 games to show the interstitial ad:

```
public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Pipe")
        {
            s.GameOver();
            targetVelocity.y = 0;
            targetVelocity.x = 0;
            cube.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            score.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            this.anime2.enabled = true;

        }


        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Ad Counter", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Ad Counter") + 1);

        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Ad Counter") > 10)
        {
            if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
            {
                interstitial.Show();
            }

            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Ad Counter", 0);
        }
    }
```

And this is my request code:

```
private void RequestInterstitial()

    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID

        string adUnitId ="ca-app -pub-3960055046097211/6145173288";

#elif UNITY_IPHONE

        string adUnitId = "INSERT_IOS_INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";

#else

        string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";

#endif

        // Initialize an InterstitialAd.

        InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);

        // Create an empty ad request.

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

        // Load the interstitial with the request.

        interstitial.LoadAd(request);
    }
```

Of course afterwards i called the method in the start().

So where is the problem?Should i put this script on an empty object?

Comment: try logging `adUnitId ` before using it and see which id you get. And have you replaced the ids in the else block with a real id?

Comment: also, do you see any error / message related to admob in logcat?

Comment: Have you tried to debug this code? Can you reach this line: interstitial.Show()? RequestInterstitial()? also check your adUnitId is correct as platform can be detected wrong for some reason

Comment: Well I've checked the adUnitId twice and its ok?How do i debug it?logcat?Because I am a new developer

Answer (score 1):

Add permission as mentioned above and call interstitial in update because it takes a while to load. Thanks

```
enter code here

InterstitialAd interstitial;
bool check;

private void RequestInterstitial()
{

     interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    interstitial.LoadAd(request);

}
void Update()
{
    if (!check) {
        if (interstitial.IsLoaded ()) {
            interstitial.Show ();
            check = true;
        }
    }
}
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Interstitial Ads you need to add some permissions on your Manifest file.

An Ad Activity that will hold the Ads. Only one is required for the whole project and request permission to use internet to load the ads (if you're not already requiring them for other stuff):

```
<manifest ...>

  <!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run-->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

  <application>

     //...

     <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
     <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

[Source](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eclipse#modify_the_manifest_file).

Comment: Everything is added before,but still they won't display